# convert(float,getdate()) sql to time in python

Tags: python-datetime

I am parsing a .csv file in python. The file is saved from a different program, which uses sql to save a date column as convert(float,getdate())+2 in a column called 'lastupdated'. It looks like this:

[image]

If I change the format to 'Time' in the .csv file, it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in Python? I've tried a few codes, but nothing has worked yet.

`datetime.strptime('43881.45608','%H:%M:%S')
pd.to_datetime(43881.45608,unit='h')`

[image]

I either get an error or an incorrect value like in the above example. Could anyone please guide me in the right direction? I'm relatively new to Python.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xlrd
df['lastupdated'].apply(lambda d: datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(d, 0)).strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```